# Plain text email is awful and unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, email

Plain-text-part of notification emails is awful and unreadable (this isn't about fanciness or design!). Here's an example (white-space is copied as is):

```
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2015 09:10:42 +0000
From: Stack Exchange <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
Subject: 4 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox
To: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 7.0.4.334











                                answer


                                Apr 29 at 7:08




                        Replace emoticons with emoji




 var map =   {
      "       










                                comment


                                Apr 29 at 6:17




                        Replace emoticons with emoji


                        @Moogs and it would be a pain to invest these 5 minutes to let it do so?











                                comment


                                Apr 29 at 6:08




                        Replace emoticons with emoji


                        @OddDev I don't think that library replaces text emoticons with unicode characters.











                                comment


                                Apr 29 at 6:05




                        Replace emoticons with emoji


                        github.com/kof/emoticons







                    Want instant inbox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS or Android!




















_________________________________________________________________________

    Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](http://meta.stackexchange.com).
            If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may [unsubscribe from this email](http://meta.stackexchan
ge.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/37594/f3f9713bb7a63574b7140d53a26d8c7f513cdebb47128994e649eceaba34be3d).


Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038
```

I've grown accustomed to automatically delete these notifications and visit the website to try to understand what they're about. Any chance that SO fixes this?

**Update:**

This is actually the text/plain part. My UA is not at fault here:

```
From do-not-reply@stackexchange.com Wed Apr 29 22:38:01 2015
Return-Path: <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
Delivered-To: hugo_barrera.io
Received: from elysion.barrera.io
    by elysion.barrera.io (Dovecot) with LMTP id HuuGNXmHQVXwawAAKWKjFg
    for <hugo_barrera.io>; Thu, 30 Apr 2015 01:38:01 +0000
Return-Path: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
Delivered-To: hugo@barrera.io
Received: from mx-out.stackexchange.com (mx-out.stackexchange.com [198.252.206.125]);
    by mx1.barrera.io (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTPS id 3677f4dc;
    TLS version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 bits=256 verify=NO;
    for <hugo@barrera.io>;
    Thu, 30 Apr 2015 01:38:01 +0000 (GMT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=stackexchange.com; s=dk;
    h=Content-Type:Message-ID:Date:Subject:Reply-To:To:From:MIME-Version; bh=EnVK4mirolKZqon1FUhFHIQhcHKYqtdSQGcoW26x6No=;
    b=hgvXQQbEs71CwjbCqHB/BywZR9q582+Cd+zYGCbHH9tTRxyxcdMjkcT5uR++tql1BXuCeRUsXxRF4ONsgdyojLEfASLZbxgz22c+zYX2rFv+spnoPz8EIGJq9mgZ9h3HtZ9N2YqdL/VZ/5P9IXDZBDErYqZE7x1zfncslmdayuc=;
Received: from [10.7.2.15] (helo=[10.7.2.107])
    by mx-out.stackexchange.com with esmtp (Exim 4.72)
    (envelope-from <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>)
    id 1YndQQ-0002ls-IA; Thu, 30 Apr 2015 01:38:02 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 7.0.4.334
From: "Stack Exchange" <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
To: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
Reply-To: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
Subject: 1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 01:38:02 +0000
Message-ID: <2.401e53547278ccb51d61@NY-WEB07>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_5EA7_32855996.8BA1A908"


------=_NextPart_000_5EA7_32855996.8BA1A908
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=0A    =0A            =0A                =0A                    =0A        =
        =0A                =0A                    =0A                      =
  =0A                            =0A                                comment=
=0A                            =0A                            =0A          =
                      Apr 29 at 22:04=0A                            =0A    =
                    =0A                    =0A                    =0A      =
                  Plain text email is awful and unreadable=0A              =
      =0A                    =0A                        Is that truly a Tex=
t/PLAIN mail, or is it your mail client's attempt to interpret a T...=0A   =
                 =0A                =0A            =0A        =0A          =
  =0A              =0A                =0A                    Want instant i=
nbox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app fo=
r iOS or Android!=0A                =0A                =0A                 =
   =0A                        =0A                            =0A           =
                     =0A                            =0A                    =
    =0A                        =0A                            =0A          =
                      =0A                            =0A                   =
     =0A                    =0A                =0A            =0A        =
=0A    =0A=0A=0A___________________________________________________________=
______________=0A
    Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](http://meta.sta=
ckexchange.com).
            If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may=
 [unsubscribe from this email](http://meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscr=
ibe/inbox/37594/f3f9713bb7a63574b7140d53a26d8c7f513cdebb47128994e649eceaba3=
4be3d).


Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038 =

------=_NextPart_000_5EA7_32855996.8BA1A908
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<snipped base64 content>
------=_NextPart_000_5EA7_32855996.8BA1A908--
```

Comment: Do it like a computer, ignore white spaces, convert everything to binary and then you can read it just like a book: `1001'0000
0110'1001
0110'0111
0110'1000
0111'0100` ?

Comment: Does it do anything interesting if you pass it through a [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) interpreter? Might be an easter egg :-)

Comment: Is that truly a `Text/PLAIN` mail, or is it your mail client's attempt to interpret a `Text/HTML` mail?  I use Alpine and am used to seeing awful mails (where the only thing uglier than the html version is the plain version), but usually not when I've explicitly signed up with the sender for a plaintext-only mail.

Comment: It's the plain-text part: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"`

Comment: I must admit, that this looks terrible. Hard to believe, that no one at SE ever took care of such thing.

Comment: Wow, a year and a half later they still send that crappy emails...

Answer (score 3):

Since this post, we have migrated email systems as part of a much larger effort for users to control opt-out, comply with GDPR, and general tech debt removal on our side. Each email now has plaintext and HTML views explicitly maintained, whereas before we stripped tags from the HTML version in a rather lazy way.

The experience here should be much better for all emails we sent save tag sets from stackexchange.com. They are the last thing moving over to the new email system as soon as we can find the time.